# Pyspark process to fill null and combine data

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have following dataframe which need to work on.

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | None | None | None | None |
| 1 | None | 3.5 | 4.4 | None | None |
| 1 | None | 4,5 | 5.5 | None | None |
| 1 | None | 6.5 | 7.5 | None | None |
| 1 | None | None | None | 8.7 | None |
| 1 | None | None | None | 7.3 | None |
| 1 | None | None | None | 9.3 | None |
| 1 | None | None | None | 10.2 | None |
| 1 | None | None | None | None | 100.2 |

The objective is to fill the empty values but also do a cartesian product of each column based on the id column. The expected output should be :

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3.5 | 4.4 | 8.7 | 100.2 |
| 1 | 1 | 3.5 | 4.4 | 7.3 | 100.2 |
| 1 | 1 | 3.5 | 4.4 | 9.3 | 100.2 |
| 1 | 1 | 3.5 | 4.4 | 10.2 | 100.2 |
| 1 | 1 | 4.5 | 5.5 | 8.7 | 100.2 |
| 1 | 1 | 4.5 | 5.5 | 7.3 | 100.2 |
| 1 | 1 | 4.5 | 5.5 | 9.3 | 100.2 |
| 1 | 1 | 4.5 | 5.5 | 10.2 | 100.2 |
| 1 | 1 | 6.5 | 7.5 | 8.7 | 100.2 |
| 1 | 1 | 6.5 | 7.5 | 7.3 | 100.2 |
| 1 | 1 | 6.5 | 7.5 | 9.3 | 100.2 |
| 1 | 1 | 6.5 | 7.5 | 10.2 | 100.2 |

If you notice, there are more records in the output and that's because I need to group but also I need to duplicate in some sort the data to get the respective values, I have tried by generating multiple dataframes and then doing a massive joins since this is only a portion of the data I'm dealing with, it's only an example.

The main issue I'm facing is regarding memory allocation issues when performing this action over multiple joins per each level. The goal is to use either Window function or other less consumption memory process. Does anyone have any idea on how can this be achived

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.